# How to add a value to a current cookie value

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm doing an advert overlay for a website. The advert must be seen by the user 3 times consecutively in 24 hours. 24 hours after the advert was first seen(when the cookie was set) the cycle starts again

I have sorted out the 24 hour cookie expiry but I don't know how to implement the value system. Once the cookie value reaches 3 the advert hides

I'm open to a php solution

Here's the scripts that have been coded so far:

```js
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
 if (days) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
 }
 else var expires = "";
 document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
 var nameEQ = name + "=";
 var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
 for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
  if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
 }
 return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
 createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var days = 1;
var advert = document.getElementById('overlay-stage');
if (readCookie('seenAdvert')) {
    advert.className = 'htmlNoPages hidden';
} else {
    advert.className = 'htmlNoPages show';
    createCookie('seenAdvert', 'yes', 1);
}
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think simple solution would be to use 8hrs cookie, `createCookie('seenAdvert', 'yes', 1/3);` would do that

Comment: Thanks but it must be seen 3 times in a row and then the advert hides. i.e 3 consecutive pages viewed in a row on the same website

Comment: So basically it will involve fetching the cookies current value, adding onto it and setting the cookie with the new value. When the cookies value reaches 3 or greater, the element is hidden. Until the cookie expires

Comment: You are on correct path